# Passing objects in java through constructor

Tags: java, object, constructor

What is better : passing an object through a constructor and save it to new reference in another class, or passing through a constructor an directly pass it to method? Is there any difference?

```
class A
{ 
  int a;
  int b;
} 

class B
{
  public A refA;

  public B(A refA)
  {
    this.refA = refA;
    methodInB(refA); 
  }

  public void methodInB(A refA)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

OR -------------------------------------------------- OR

```
class A
{ 
  int a;
  int b;
} 

class B
{
  public B(A refA)
  {
    methodInB(refA);
  }

  public void methodInB(A refA)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need the stored reference for anything? You are in both cases passing the reference directly to the method. Storing less is actually preferable.

Comment: Do you need it in `B`? If yes, set it. If not, don't. There's no "preferred" way because they're two different snippets.

Comment: Depends on circumstances.  Generally I think the first is preferred.  Classes should encapsulate their behavior. However, in this case you are *calling* an overridable method from the ctor.  That's bad practice.  `methodInB()` should be private or final.

Comment: Does your class `B` need a class variable of type `A`?

Comment: If you have refA stored as a variable, then why bother passing it to methodInB?  Unless methodInB is going to be used with a different A object somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether A is integral part of B or not same goes for the methodInB. If we don't put A's reference in B then methodInB becomes kind of a utility method, which should better be static. If it's not a utility then it has a dependency on A and A's reference should be put in B.

Also if there are other methods in B which may need the same A instance to operate on, it's better to keep A's reference saved inside B.

If methodInB is acting as a utility then it should be put in a utility class with static modifier taking A and B type parameters.

Check below:

```
public class A { }
public class B { }

public class MyUtility {
    public static void methodInB(A a, B b) {
        //operate on a and b
    }
}

//  MyUtility can also have a dependency on A and B both and thus make methodInB a non static methodInB
public class MyUtilityBean {
    private A a;
    private B b;

    public void methodInB() {
        //operate on a and b
    }
}

//Other wise A acts as a dependency of B

public class B {
    private A a;
    public void methodInB() {
        //operate on a
    }
}
```